# How to Pass Multiple Dissolve Fields in VBA Code of ibasicgeoprocessor.dissolve Method

Tags: arcgis-9.3

When we use the ibasicgeoprocessor.dissolve method it supports only one dissolve field but if we pass more than one dissolve field then it gives an exception: `value does not fall with in the range exception`

Please give me any VBA, VB.Net, C#.Net code example of the ibasicgeoprocessor.Dissolve method having multiple dissolve fields.

Comment: How are you passing in the string of fields? You can also use the Geoprocessing Dissolve tool programmatically